# adding time delta specific to row (Date time Cleaning)(Date time)

Tags: pandas, datetime, time-series, data-cleaning, timedelta

series data I have 2 files. Each data observation has 20 sec delay

file 1

[image: file 1]

file 2

[image: file 2]

Expected Output

[image: expected output]

What I have done so far

[image: my output]

with code

[image: my code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a [**`date_range()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) with `freq='20s'`.

Note that I changed April 31 to a valid date. I assume the real data will have valid dates.

```py
dfs = []
for file in files:
    column_name = pd.read_csv(file, index_col=False).columns[0]
    df = pd.read_csv(file, index_col=False, names=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'], skiprows=1)
    
    # generate date range with frequency of 20 seconds
    start = pd.to_datetime(column_name, dayfirst=True)
    df['col4'] = pd.date_range(start=start, periods=len(df), freq='20s')
    
    dfs.append(df)
df = pd.concat(dfs)

#    col1  col2  col3                col4
# 0     3     5     6 2005-03-31 23:59:00
# 1     4     6     7 2005-03-31 23:59:20
# 2     8     9    10 2005-03-31 23:59:40
# 0    10    20    30 2007-06-01 23:59:00
# 1    40    50    60 2007-06-01 23:59:20
# 2    70    80    90 2007-06-01 23:59:40
```

---

To change the frequency after concatenating, you can [**`groupby()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) each sub-dataframe (each one restarts at index 0) and regenerate a [**`date_range()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) with the new `freq`:

```py
freq = '30s'
df['col4'] = df.groupby((df.index == 0).cumsum())['col4'].apply(
    lambda g: pd.Series(pd.date_range(g[0], periods=len(g), freq=freq)))

#    col1  col2  col3                col4
# 0     3     5     6 2005-03-31 23:59:00
# 1     4     6     7 2005-03-31 23:59:30
# 2     8     9    10 2005-04-01 00:00:00
# 0    10    20    30 2007-01-06 23:59:00
# 1    40    50    60 2007-01-06 23:59:30
# 2    70    80    90 2007-01-07 00:00:00
```

Comment: hi @tdy, just wondering after concatenation, if we want to change frequency to 30s do I have to do all of this again or is there a way to do it from 'col4'

Comment: @sra yes it's possible, i updated the answer with one option

Comment: @sra sounds like your csvs stored the index (usually not a good idea) so instead of `index_col=False` you need `index_col=0`